# \citeform depending on value of counter

Tags: bibliographies

I have inherited a LaTeX style which distinguishes between two types of references (selected own work, other work). The former are supposed to 
appear in the form "[R1]", the latter in the format "[4]".

The way this is achieved is by defining different bibliography types.
If an entry is part of the first category, its counter value is increased
by 1000. This is actually working.

There is also a `\citeform` command in the stylefile which is supposed to replace citation keys > 1000 by "R" and the original counter value, that is num-1000.

For some reason, the second part is not working, and the citations keep their numbers 1001, 1002, etc.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,DIV11,BCOR10mm,twoside]{scrartcl}

\input{style.sty}

\begin{document}

  Citation test \cite{P5:test}.

  Does this work? \cite{test}


  \section{References}

  \begin{projectbibliography}
    \Bibitem{P5:test}  own paper number 1
  \end{projectbibliography}


  \begin{otherbibliography}
    \Bibitem{test}  other paper number 1
  \end{otherbibliography}

\end{document}
```

And here is the content of style.sty:

```
\makeatletter

\newif\if@SFB
\@SFBfalse
\newbox\@SFB
\newbox\@BULLET
\newcount\my@bibcount
\newcount\my@bibcountP
\newcount\my@bibtempcount

\newenvironment{subbibliography}[2]%
     { 
       \global\setbox\@SFB=\hbox{#1}\ifdim \wd\@SFB>0pt%
       \global\@SFBtrue \else \global\@SFBfalse %%%%%%%%%%\subsubsection*{#1\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase#1}{\MakeUppercase#1}}
       \fi%
       \global\setbox\@BULLET=\hbox{#2}%
      \list{%% DEFINE HOW THE ITEM APPEARS
        %% save list position
        \my@bibtempcount=\c@enumiv%
        %% add bibcounter
        \if@SFB%
        \advance\my@bibtempcount by \my@bibcountP%
        \else%
        \advance\my@bibtempcount by \my@bibcount%
        \fi%
        %% make label
        \@biblabel{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\unhcopy\@BULLET% for bullet in brackets
          \unhcopy\@SFB\@arabic\my@bibtempcount}}%
%      \list{\@biblabel{\unhcopy\@SFB\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\unhcopy\@BULLET% for bullet in brackets
                 \unhcopy\@SFB99}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth%
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep%
            \@openbib@code%
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty%
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy%
      \clubpenalty4000%
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty%
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m%
    }
     {\def\@noitemerr%
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `subbibliography' environment}}%
       %% save bibcounter
       \if@SFB%
       \global\advance\my@bibcountP by \c@enumiv%
       \else%
       \global\advance\my@bibcount  by \c@enumiv%
       \fi%
       \endlist}
\newenvironment{otherbibliography}{\begin{subbibliography}{}{}}{\end{subbibliography}}
\newenvironment{projectbibliography}{\begin{subbibliography}{R}{}}{\end{subbibliography}}
%%%%%% Neues token fuer bibitem
\def\Bibitem{\@ifnextchar[\@lbibitem\@Bibitem}
\def\@Bibitem#1{\count255=\the\value{\@listctr}%
                \if@SFB%
                \advance\count255 by \my@bibcountP%
                \advance\count255 by 1001%
                \else%
                \advance\count255 by \my@bibcount%
                \advance\count255 by 1%
                \fi%
                \item\if@filesw %
                \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\count255}}\fi%
                \unhcopy\@BULLET% bullet comes AFTER bibitem
                \ignorespaces%               
              }
%              
\providecommand\citeform[1]{{\def\@b@b{#1}\if ?\@b@b \@b@b \else  \count255=#1 \ifnum #1>1000\count255=#1
\loop\ifnum\count255>1000\advance\count255 by -1000
\repeat P\the\count255\else\the\count255\fi\fi}}
\makeatother

\endinput
```

Comment: Please, make a minimal example: such a code snippet won't help.

Comment: Hi egreg, I have added the full example, but the formatting is messed up. I will try and change that as soon as possible. Cheers, Martin

Comment: The macro `\citeform` is never called.

Comment: I agree. I just verified that \citeform{1004} gives me P4. However, how do I apply \citeform to the reference number produced by the \cite command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load also the package `cite`, but *after* your `style` package. This way the command `\citeform` will do its job. Otherwise it's never called.